# Exibir determinada imagem para derminados números

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte `<input>` e `<img>`  na página.

```
<input class="form-control" id="cordenadasaqui" value="47644.63956 74592.843" readonly>

<img id="imagemaqui" src="http://www.meusite.com/los-santos.jpg">
```

> Preciso fazer com que seja exibida uma imagem diferente para cada conjunto de cordenadas exibida.

#### Exemplo

---

Se o `<input>` acima estiver com o `value=" "` contendo nos primeiros 11 caracteres:

```
47644.63956
```

**a imagem exibida será:**

```
<img id="imagemaqui" src="http://www.meusite.com/los-santos.jpg">
```

---

Se estiver com o `value=" "` contendo os seguintes números nos primeiros 11 caracteres:

```
87635.98456
```

**a imagem exibida será:**

```
<img id="imagemaqui" src="http://www.meusite.com/las-venturas.jpg">
```

---

#### Para simplificar a pergunta

> No `value=" "` será carregado um determinado conjunto de números, e então deve-se pegar apenas os 11 primeiros caracteres (10 números e 1 ponto ".").

**Se** esses 11 primeiros caracteres forem `47644.63956` = `los-santos.jpg`

**Se** esses 11 primeiros caracteres forem `87635.98456` = `las-venturas.jpg`

E por aí vai... Como fazer isto?

Comment: os valores ja vao vir preenchidos no input? ou quando o usuario digitar aparecerá a imagem?

Comment: Já vão vir preenchidos no input amigo :D

Comment: pretende usar js?

Comment: Acho que seria uma alternativa. :)

Comment: vou fazer um código aqui e ja respondo sua pergunta...

Comment: Obrigado amigo! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que esse código solucione seu problema. Ao carregar a pagina ele pega o valor do input e compara de acordo com o que voce disse. E fazendo a atribuiçao na imagem:

```
<input class="form-control" id="cordenadasaqui" value="87635.98456 74592.843" readonly>

<img id="imagemaqui" src="http://www.meusite.com/los-santos.jpg">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   var coordenadas= $("#cordenadasaqui").val().substr(0,11);
   var img="";
if(coordenadas=="47644.63956"){
img="http://www.meusite.com/los-santos.jpg";
    }
else if(coordenadas=="87635.98456"){
        img="http://www.meusite.com/las-venturas.jpg";
    }
    $("#imagemaqui").attr("src",img);
});
</script>
```

Usei Jquery. Espero ter ajudado!!

Comment: Vou testar agora! :D

Comment: Ficou perfeito!!! Muito obrigado, meus parabéns pelo seu conhecimento e por ajudar os leigos aqui no Sopt! :) kkkkk...

Comment: kkk De nada, foi um prazer ajudar :)

Comment: Amigo, você poderia dar um exemplo adicional de ao invés de atribuir uma imagem, atribuir um texto? Invés de um `<img>` um `<font>` ?

Comment: Posta uma outra pergunta, porque não compreendi bem. Mas acho que seguiria a mesma logica, só que em vez de  `$("#imagemaqui").attr("src",img);` seria  algo desse tipo `$("font").html("seu texto");`

Comment: Vlww!!! Tive que mudar para: `$("#imagemaqui").text(img);`

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu :)